# Concatenate varying number of rows in one column by one keyword in Excel

Tags: excel, concatenation, vba

Can you help me understand how to Concatenate all rows of a bunch of records in one column, but with varying numbers of rows and delineated by a keyword indicating the first row like 'File*#' ?  An example:

```
1   file# x  stuff...  
2   more stuff  
3   more stuff.   
4   file# x   stuff...  
5   more stuff  
6   File #    stuff  
7   File#   stuff
```

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. Will the transpose button work?

Comment: The problem is I have a thousand records with 2-10 rows each in one column. Transpose could work if I could automate that process triggered by all rows for each File#.

Comment: So in the example above you would like to see rows 1, 2, and 3 in row 1, column a; rows 4 and 5 in row 2, column a, etc. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly.  Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example with actual data? What is a typical file # and 'more stuff'?

Comment: The records are monstrous.  I concatenated about 90 cols into 2-10 rows in one col for each record.

Comment: if you don't want to provide more data/details to the community to sort out the issue as e.g. the data is sensitive (and fake data wouldn't help us to figure out what would be the right solution), I'd recommend copying the whole sheet into a text file and edit with notepad++ or scite for example, find-replace "\r\nmore stuff" with "more stuff" so you text-edit-pull together your data to a single line (if that makes sense). After that, import back the thing to Excel (and tadaa, now it'll look the way you want)

Comment: How's this? 
Original:
 COL A<br />
1  File# 2344 a bunch of text here multiple column
2  2nd row more data
3 3rd row more data for
4 4th row all in
5 File# 3498 and a bunch
6 2nd row more data
7 3rd row for this record

Desired: 

COL B
File# 2344 a bunch of text here multiple column 2nd row more data 3rd row more data for 4th row all in 

File# 3498 and a bunch 2nd row more data 3rd row for this record

Comment: I honest to god cannot figure out how to make this more clear. I have one column with many rows. Each record is delineated by a row containing a word 'File#'. That row and one, two, three others have more data that relate to that record. A new record starts the same way. First row has File# and then has 1-10 more rows of data. I simply want to concat all the rows for one record into one cell in an adjacent column. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a better way but I think this will work for you:

```
Sub Test()

Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim x As Variant
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim aSht As Worksheet

Set aSht = ActiveSheet
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
i = 1
Do While r <> ""
    If Left(r.Offset(i, 0), 6) = "File #" Or r.Offset(i, 0) = "" Then
        x = r.Resize(i, 1).Value2
        ReDim arr(1 To UBound(x, 1))
        For lRow = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
            arr(lRow) = x(lRow, 1)
        Next
        If aSht.Cells(aSht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Value = "" Then
            aSht.Cells(aSht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Value = Join(arr, ";")
        Else
            aSht.Cells(aSht.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Join(arr, ";")
        End If
        Set r = r.Offset(i, 0)
        i = 1
    Else
        i = i + 1
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

NOTE: There must be a minimum of 2 rows for a File. In other words, row 1 is File..., and row 2 is stuff. Each File row must begin: `File` (space) `#`. I can make it more flexible but it will work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Brian! I haven't been getting emails of responses so I just discovered this. I will try this the next round in about a week. The last one I had to manually slog through. I do appreciate your help!